# How can I display a div as many times as is stored in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, echo

I cannot post the exact code, but I want to display divs in the screen that look the same.
I also want to display `x` number of divs on the screen, `x` being a PHP variable storing a number.

I was thinking to:

- List item
- echo the div and
- do this x times (x = the PHP var), with a `for()` method.

Comment: You know the solution, code it then !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember, we need Minimal, complete, Verifiable Examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. When you are finished, click `edit` to edit your question, so that we may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent on the array type there are a number of options you can chose:

If the variable is an array then you can use a foreach loop which will look like this:

```
foreach($array as $value){
    echo('<div>content</div>');
}
```

You could also use a for loop (if you know how the value of the variable) such as:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $row['db_variable']; $i++){
    echo('<div>content</div>');
}
```

EDIT: use the for loop and change '$row['db_variable']' to your mysql result.

Comment: The variable is a number from my mysql db.

Comment: Thanks! I will try out

Answer (score 1):

You can try and modify this code, this should work.
Set a variable `$number` then do something like this:

If you just want to repeat static html:

```
<?php for( $i = 0; $i<5; $i++ ){ ?>
    <div class = "jumbotron">
      <!-- Do whatever you need here -->
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

If you have an array $number and you want to do for each value in the array:

```
  <?php foreach($number as $r): ?>
     <div class = "jumbotron">
       <!-- Do whatever you need here -->
     </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Let me know.

Comment: And what is $r?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a while loop for this task. Say you want the div to be displayed 10 times, you would use the following code:

```
$i = 10;
while($i != 0){
   $i--;
   /* Code to execute, maybe echo something out, do whatever - but it will do it 10 times */
}
```